# What equations of the flow ensure that gradient descends on manifold given by constraints $g(x) = 0$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, optimization, maxima-minima, fixed-points, gradient-flows

When one tries to find (local) minima of a function $f(x)$ under the constraint $g(x)=0$, the classical approach that is taught in analysis courses is to find the zeros of the gradient of the Lagrange function $$\mathcal{L}(x,\lambda) = f(x) - \lambda g(x).$$

Apparently, at a zero $x_0,\lambda_0$ of the gradient of $\mathcal{L}$ we have
$$ \nabla_f(x_0) = \lambda_0 \nabla_g(x_0)$$
and
$$g(x_0) =0 $$

such that in particular at this point our constraint is fulfilled.
Now, however, I wondered how one would implement a gradient that flows up to this point of minimum, and in particular how one does that while staying on the manifold given by $g(x)=0$ at any point in time.

I initially thought that by simply doing

$$ \frac{d}{dt}\begin{pmatrix} x \\ \lambda \end{pmatrix} = \nabla \mathcal{L}(x,\lambda)$$

one would achieve this. However, it does not seem to be as obvious any more, since 1. the zeros of the lagrange function we are seeking are saddle points, not minima, and 2. if one plugs in $$ \frac{d}{dt} g(x(t))$$ this results in some set of equations that do not seem to indicate that we stay on the manifold.

So, my question is, what would an appropiate flow look like that stays on the manifold and approaches a minimum?
I.e., looking for some set of equations

$$\frac{d}{dt}\begin{pmatrix} x \\ \lambda \end{pmatrix}  = \begin{pmatrix} u(x,\lambda) \\ v(x,\lambda) \end{pmatrix} $$

such that in particular

$$ \frac{d}{dt} g(x(t)) = \nabla_g(x(t)) u(x(t),\lambda(t)) = 0$$

and a local minimum is a fixed point of the equations.

Comment: I didn't read your question in detail, however I am sure that the answer is somewhere in [the book of Boumal](http://sma.epfl.ch/~nboumal/book/index.html) on optimization on manifolds.

Comment: Let me assume $\nabla g(x) \neq 0$ for all $x$ such that $g(x) = 0$, so that $M = \{x : g(x) = 0\}$ is a manifold. If you initialize your trajectory on $M$, and you follow the ODE $x'(t) = -P_{x(t)} \nabla f(x(t))$ where $P_x$ is the orthogonal projector to the tangent space of $M$ at $x$ (to which $\nabla g(x)$ is normal), then the solution $x(t)$ stays on the manifold and the value of the cost function $f(x(t))$ decreases as $t \to \infty$. This trajectory may or may not converge to a minimizer, but at least its accumulation points are critical points of $f$ under the constraint $g(x) = 0$.

Comment: I do not discuss continuous time flows in my book (though you may be interested in Section 7.7 for a discussion of how Riemannian optimization and the classical Lagrangian / KKT perspectives fit together). For gradient flows on manifolds, you may enjoy Helmke and Moore 1994, https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4471-3467-1.